# How to merge/combine two SqlDataReader Objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am working on a SQL server monitoring project. In this I want to fetch data from all the SQL Server instances installed on machine. For this, I have written a CLR Stored procedure, in which the data came in two different SqlDataReader objects and I want to merge these two datareder objects.

Is it possible to merge two SQLdatareader objects?

Following is the situation where I am facing this issue:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionSting of 1st SQLServerInstance")
string query = "select dbid,uid,cpu from [master].[sys].sysprocesses";

SqlCommand SelectCmmand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);            
SqlDataReader rd1;            
conn.Open();
rd1 = SelectCmmand.ExecuteReader();
conn.Close();

conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionSting of 2nd SQLServerInstance")

SqlCommand SelectCmmand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);            
SqlDataReader rd2;            
conn.Open();
rd2 = SelectCmmand.ExecuteReader();
conn.Close();

SqlPipe sp;
sp = SqlContext.Pipe;
sp.Send(?????);
```

Now, sp.Send(??) method wants SQLDataReader object as a parameter where I want to send the above data fetched from two different connectionstring.

So, How should i merge/combine rd1 and rd2?

Answer (score 3):

You could load two DataTables with the readers, merge them and call `DataTable.CreateDataReader()`.

For example (not tested):

```
DataTable dt1 = New DataTable();
dt1.Load(rd1);
DataTable dt2 = New DataTable();
dt2.Load(rd2);
dt1.Merge(dt2);
DataTableReader mainReader = dt1.CreateDataReader();
Common.DbDataReader reader = (Common.DbDataReader)mainReader;
sp.Send((SqlClient.SqlDataReader)reader);
```

- [DataTable.Load(iDataReader)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb.aspx)
- [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [DataTable.CreateDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.createdatareader.aspx)

**Edit**: I'm afraid that my code does not work because you cannot cast the `DbDataReader` to a `SqlDataReader`.

One way would be (again, not tested) to use [SqlPipe.SendResultsRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlpipe.sendresultsrow.aspx) to send all records row by row.

Comment: something like this SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow();

Comment: Yes, We can send Row by Row but this will impact on performance.... Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

You can't merge SqlDataReaders.

Have you considered just returning two result sets? It would be as though you did SELECT * FROM Table1, followed by SELECT * FROM Table2 in the same batch or stored procedure. On the client side, use SqlDataReader.NextResult() to advance from the first result set to the second one.

Comment: Actually this also wont work for my situation i want to fetch data from two different SQL Server so connection string is different for both the queries. if i use as suggested by you then it will be fire on single database.

Comment: I thought you were fetching data from two instances, and returning it from a single CLR SP. So the client only has one connection string, and only issues one query, right? So why can't the CLR SP return two result sets in response to that query?

Answer (score 1):

First convert your datareader to datatables

```
SqlCommand SelectCmmand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);            
SqlDataReader rd1;    
conn.Open(); 

rd1 = SelectCmmand.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Load(rd1);

conn.Close();

SqlCommand SelectCmmand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);            
SqlDataReader rd2;            
conn.Open();

rd2 = SelectCmmand.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2.Load(rd2);

conn.Close();
```

Then merge both of them

```
dt1.Merge(dt2);
```

Note the data from table 2 will added to table 1

Now convert back to data reader

```
DataTableReader dtr;
dtr = dt1.CreateDataReader();        
SqlPipe sp;
sp = SqlContext.Pipe;
sp.Send(dtr);
```

Comment: The [Send method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127317.aspx) takes a SqlDataReader not a DataTableReader. This won't work like my answer.